# Change element to input then get updated record

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

I have a label which has an ID of `lblUserPhoneNumber` and when I double click on the element, I want it to change into a textbox, which so far is working fine. Then when I click outside of the textbox, I want it to convert back to a label (Which is done) and display the updated records into the console.

The problem I am having is that is it not displaying the updated result, only the previous result

Before: 12345678910

After: 12345678911

Displays: 12345678910 (The before result)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#lblUserPhoneNumber").dblclick(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();

        var input = $('<input id="lblUserPhoneNumber" type="text" value="' + text + '" />')

        $(this).text('').append(input);
        input.select();

        input.blur(function () {
            var text = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().text(text);
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });


    $("#lblUserPhoneNumber").change(function () {
        console.log($(this).html());
    });
});
```

So here I have the .change event which is called, I have other events such as focusout but none give me the results I am looking for, is what I got on the right track or am I completely of?

Comment: Tip: Don't append the element, replace it.

Comment: Works fine for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vtmcjb7L/1/** ?

Comment: Adeno, check the console, it will show the previous result and not the updated result.

Comment: Duplicate Ids, Yours will be invalid HTML. As `$("#lblUserPhoneNumber").append('<input id="lblUserPhoneNumber"')`

Comment: Yeah, I am looking what MelanciaUK suggested and using replace instead.

Comment: The console is showing the wrong number because the change event fires before the blur event, that is to be expected ?

Comment: Also, I can't understand this bit: `$(this).parent().text(text);`. What's the `parent` element?

Comment: An `input` element doesn't have `HTML` contents, so `.html()` won't work properly. That would be right: `console.log($(this).val());`

Comment: If I didn't get you wrong, this would be what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/uxL0dhdf/

Comment: That is very very close MelanciaUK! I can work with that to adjust it to my needs, if you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some considerations.

Try to avoid replacing elements with others and keeping the same `id`. It would lead to confusion.

When handling the `change` event of an `input`, handle the `input` instead. It generally doesn't work in the former way.

To display the contents of an `input`, `select` or `textarea`, use `.val()` instead of `.html()`.

As you're manipulating the `DOM` dynamically and some elements might not be there all the time, use event delegation.

```
$(function () {
    // Using event delegation.
    $(document).on('dblclick', '#lblUserPhoneNumber', function () {
        var text = $(this).text();

        // Here we use a different id for the input.
        var input = $('<input>', {
            id: 'inputUserPhoneNumber',
            type: 'text',
            value: text
        });

        // Replacing the label with the new input.
        $(this).replaceWith(input).select();
    });

    // Using event delegation. Also we attach multiple event handlers at once.
    $(document).on({
        input: function () {
            console.log($(this).val());
        },
        blur: function () {
            var value = $(this).val();

            var label = $('<span>', {
                id: 'lblUserPhoneNumber',
                text: value
            });

            // Replacing the input with the new label.
            $(this).replaceWith(label);
        }
    }, '#inputUserPhoneNumber');
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/uxL0dhdf/)